# How do i get the last value of a metric depending on label?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to get the last value of a metric depending on a label and show them on a table. Lets say we have a some metrics x with some labels ordered in time:

```
x {k1="1", k2="1"} 0
x {k1="1", k2="2"} 0
x {k1="2", k2="3"} 0
```

I would like to have them on a table such as:

| k1 | k2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

Also, i dont know if its possible, but can i add a search funtion to the table so i can search by, for example, the column k1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Table panel, add the metric you want to show and turn on the "Instant" option:

[image]

In the "Transform" tab, add a "Labels to fields" transformation so labels so each label will become a separate field. Add a "Organize fields" transformation to hide some fields like the "Time" or the "Value" ones.

[image]

More information at the Grafana documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/transformations/types-options/).